# Happy Birthday everybody

Tags: discussion, site-activity

SE requires that I type some words in here too, so Happy Birthday everybody!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We're all old geezers now hooray~

[image]

**Edit:** The party is not saddle-path stable; it grows out of proportion just like our parents utter confusion at our excitement. *The party never stops.*

Comment: You are clearly violating the site's policies, http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/a/1444/61, :) , so I guess you need to provide some inside information on this hard party -for example is it, at least, saddle-path stable?

Comment: Edited with an answer. Let me know if it needs more detail. :)

Comment: Well it may explode in levels of the aggregate variables, but what about in per capita terms? Or in per party-efficiency unit terms? Doesn't the _growth rate_ settles to a long-term positive value?

Comment: I think everyone parties until the universe explodes, but who knows when that will happen? Until then I figure per capita partying grows exponentially.